# Looking for PHP/Flash graphics library for interactive networked object presentation

Tags: php, image, graphics, libraries

We are looking for a PHP library something like **[graphviz.org](http://graphviz.org/)** which generates an image of a networked groups of objects as shown below. Graphviz also enables you to make each of the nodes a hyperlink, but we are looking for something more interactive, e.g. even with Flash that would be able to react to a click which deletes a node and quickly redraws that area so the other nodes fill in the space, etc.

**Does anyone know of a PHP library which generates networked object maps like this but that are also interactive so that nodes can easily added and deleted etc.?**

[image]

Comment: @Edward: Does it have to be PHP? http://prefuse.org/ offers this using http://flare.prefuse.org/.

Comment: I don't think you'll find many PHP libraries to generate a Flash movie. It's probably better to find an existing Flash application.

Comment: it doesn't have to be written in PHP, just that the API be accessible via PHP since we want to build it into our Kohana framework.

Comment: you'll spend too many memory/time generating each time that thing. this should be a flash app. you can communicate with flash via js.

Comment: @s3v3n: Memory/time could be saved by caching the image after it is initially generated; it need not be a Flash-based solution.

Comment: @Kyle: He needs to redraw the graph after deleting a node, so cache wouldn't help.
@Edward: I saw beautiful java implementations of oriented graphs, maybe it may help.

Answer (score 1):

You can give jsPlumb a try:
http://code.google.com/p/jsplumb/

Demo:
http://jsplumb.org/jquery/dynamicAnchorsDemo.html

Answer (score 0):

JsPlumb is cool but you have to position the nodes yourself. 
Take a look at http://arborjs.org. It will take care of positioning. The problem there is when you try the examples keep an eye on your cpu usage in firefox :(
See also: 
http://www.graphdracula.net/showcase/
http://flare.prefuse.org/demo
http://mbostock.github.com/protovis/ex/force.html
http://js-graph-it.sourceforge.net/index.html
https://github.com/jackrusher/jssvggraph
http://code.google.com/p/jsdot/
http://cytoscapeweb.cytoscape.org/demo
http://flare.prefuse.org/launch/apps/dependency_graph
http://hypertree.woot.com.ar/

I have been in your boat bro. If you can take care of node positioning yourself stick with JsPlumb. They just released 1.3.1 and its a nice release.